# printing the address of the name of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

:)

this is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char num[11] = { "Mississippi" };

    printf("%p\n", &num); // prints 0x7fffe44a5eb0
    printf("%p\n", num);  // prints 0x7fffe44a5eb0
    printf("%c\n", *num); // prints M

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

why do I get the same address for:

```
printf("%p\n", &num);
```

and for:

```
printf("%p\n", num);
```

?

shouldn't &num print the address of the pointer itself and num print the address of the 'cell' where M is stored?

any input is greatly appreciated!
cheers

Comment: The adress of the pointer **is** the adress of the first index.

Comment: My suggested duplicate is also the first google hit (for me) for googling your question's title...

Answer (score 3):

No, an array is not a pointer. But it can *decay* to a pointer to its first element. Which is why `num` is the same as `&num[0]`. The type of this pointer is `char *`.

The expression `&num` is a totally different one though, as it's a pointer to the array itself. The type of this is `char (*)[11]`. It just so happens that both `num` (and therefore `&num[0]`) and `&num` are pointing to the same location, but since they are different types they are semantically different.

Somewhat "graphically" you could see your array like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| M | i | s | s | i | s | s | i | p | p | i |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
^   ^   ^                                   ^
|   |   |                                   |
|   |   &num[2] ...                         &num[11]
|   |                                       |
|   &num[1]                                 (&num)[1]
|
&num[0]
|
&num
```

And to repeat, plain `num` will *decay* (i.e. be translated by the compiler) to `&num[0]`. And both `&num` and `&num[0]` points to the same location, but are of different types.

---

On another note, remember that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings. This *null-terminator* is what makes a string a string, and all string-handling functions use this terminator to know where the end of the string is.

You array does not have the space for this terminator.

Comment: thank you for responding! I still don't understand, though, why the address of the pointer itself and the value of the pointer could ever be the same. it's like the pointer is pointing on itself...which should be useless?

Comment: @Bobstanley Updated with an "image" to hopefully make it clearer.